# C# thread Windows phone Task and Dispatcher

Tags: c#

I am trying to make the code return a messageBox after the click of a button.
After the click the screen did not freeze, nor did the catch return an error.
When debugging I get an Unauthorized access error. Both `routedEventArg` and `EventArg` work with the button.
Using the `Dispatcher` without  the lambda expression gives the wrong return type.

I have two methods in total.
First `StartRunning` with the try-catch and the `Running` method which returns a `Task` type.

```
private void StartRunning(object sender, EventArgs args)
{   

    try
    {
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => { Running(); });
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}

public async Task Running()
{
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        MessageBox.Show("hello");
    });
}
```

Comment: It looks like a nonsense what you are doing. Why not simply show `MessageBox` in button click event handler? What problem are you solving?

Comment: There is also no `routedEventArg` in your shown code. What is the wrong type returned by `Dispatcher` when using it without the lambda? We need a lot more detail to be able to help

Comment: Mr. Sinatr I know it look like nonsense, but it is not. Calling message box directly will now help me because I am trying to get other methods Asyncronously. Mr. Bernd both routedEventArg and eventArg can be use in order to make a button work in my case I chose event arg. Wrong type I guess it need to be a void type for most thread to return a method